Why does my scrollbar shift the grid to the left
Trying to make a weekly calendar view. When I add the scrollbar, it shifts the grid to the left.
This is the best code I came up with. Still not solving the problem.
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import calendar
from datetime import datetime

class CalendarApp:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Calendar")
        self.root.state('zoomed')  # Maximize window to fit the screen

        self.current_year = datetime.now().year
        self.current_month = datetime.now().month
        self.today = datetime.now()

        self.nav_frame = tk.Frame(self.root)
        self.nav_frame.pack(fill='x', pady=10)

        self.left_frame = tk.Frame(self.root, width=200, borderwidth=1, relief="solid")
        self.left_frame.pack(side='left', fill='y', padx=5, pady=5)

        self.right_frame = tk.Frame(self.root, borderwidth=1, relief="solid")
        self.right_frame.pack(side='left', expand=True, fill='both', padx=5, pady=5)

        self.create_navigation()
        self.create_year_view()
        self.show_week_view()  # Show the weekly view in the right frame

    def create_navigation(self):
        prev_button = tk.Button(self.nav_frame, text="<", command=self.prev_year)
        prev_button.pack(side='left', padx=10)

        self.year_label = tk.Label(self.nav_frame, text=str(self.current_year), font=("Arial", 24))
        self.year_label.pack(side='left', padx=10)

        next_button = tk.Button(self.nav_frame, text=">", command=self.next_year)
        next_button.pack(side='left', padx=10)

    def create_year_view(self):
        self.year_label.config(text=str(self.current_year))
        self.clear_frame(self.left_frame)

        canvas = tk.Canvas(self.left_frame, borderwidth=1, relief="solid")  # Use canvas for proper width
        scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self.left_frame, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
        scrollable_frame = tk.Frame(canvas)

        scrollable_frame.bind(
            "<Configure>",
            lambda e: canvas.configure(
                scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")
            )
        )

        canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=scrollable_frame, anchor="nw")
        canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set, width=200)  # Fixed width for canvas

        canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")

        # Bind mouse wheel event for scrolling
        canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", lambda event: self.on_mouse_wheel(event, canvas))
        canvas.bind_all("<Button-4>", lambda event: self.on_mouse_wheel(event, canvas))
        canvas.bind_all("<Button-5>", lambda event: self.on_mouse_wheel(event, canvas))

        calendar.setfirstweekday(calendar.MONDAY)  # Set Monday as the first day of the week

        for month in range(1, 13):
            self.create_month_overview(scrollable_frame, month)

    def create_month_overview(self, parent_frame, month):
        month_frame = tk.Frame(parent_frame, borderwidth=1, relief="solid")
        month_frame.pack(fill='x', padx=10, pady=10)  # Reduced padding

        month_button = tk.Button(month_frame, text=calendar.month_name[month], font=("Arial", 11, "bold"),
                                 command=lambda m=month: self.show_month_view(m))
        month_button.pack(fill='x')

        days_frame = tk.Frame(month_frame)
        days_frame.pack(fill='x')

        days = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]
        for col, day in enumerate(days):
            day_label = tk.Label(days_frame, text=day, font=("Arial", 10), borderwidth=1, relief="solid")
            day_label.grid(row=0, column=col, sticky="nsew")

        days_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        days_frame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        days_frame.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
        days_frame.grid_columnconfigure(3, weight=1)
        days_frame.grid_columnconfigure(4, weight=1)
        days_frame.grid_columnconfigure(5, weight=1)
        days_frame.grid_columnconfigure(6, weight=1)

        month_days = calendar.monthcalendar(self.current_year, month)
        for row, week in enumerate(month_days, start=1):
            for col, day in enumerate(week):
                if day == 0:
                    day_label = tk.Label(days_frame, text="", borderwidth=1, relief="solid")
                else:
                    day_label = tk.Label(days_frame, text=str(day), borderwidth=1, relief="solid")
                    if self.current_year == self.today.year and month == self.today.month and day == self.today.day:
                        day_label.config(bg="lightblue")
                    day_label.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event, m=month, d=day: self.show_week_view(m, d))
                day_label.grid(row=row, column=col, sticky="nsew", padx=0, pady=0)  # Reduced padding

    def on_mouse_wheel(self, event, canvas):
        if event.num == 5 or event.delta == -120:
            canvas.yview_scroll(1, "units")
        elif event.num == 4 or event.delta == 120:
            canvas.yview_scroll(-1, "units")

    def show_week_view(self):
        self.clear_frame(self.right_frame)

        canvas = tk.Canvas(self.right_frame, borderwidth=1, relief="solid")
        canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

        scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self.right_frame, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
        scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")

        scrollable_frame = tk.Frame(canvas)
        scrollable_frame.bind(
            "<Configure>",
            lambda e: canvas.configure(
                scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")
            )
        )

        canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=scrollable_frame, anchor="nw")
        canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

        days = ["Time", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
        times = [f"{h:02d}:{m:02d}" for h in range(5, 24) for m in (0, 15, 30, 45)]

        # Create headers
        for col, day in enumerate(days):
            day_label = tk.Label(scrollable_frame, text=day, font=("Arial", 14, "bold"), borderwidth=1, relief="solid")
            day_label.grid(row=0, column=col, sticky="nsew")

        # Create time slots and gridlines
        row_height = 3  # Increase row height by using the height attribute
        for row, time in enumerate(times, start=1):
            time_label = tk.Label(scrollable_frame, text=time, font=("Arial", 12), borderwidth=1, relief="solid", height=row_height)
            time_label.grid(row=row, column=0, sticky="nsew")

            for col in range(1, 8):
                slot_label = tk.Label(scrollable_frame, text="", borderwidth=1, relief="solid", height=row_height)
                slot_label.grid(row=row, column=col, sticky="nsew")

        # Configure column and row weights for equal distribution
        for i in range(8):
            scrollable_frame.grid_columnconfigure(i, weight=1)
        for i in range(len(times) + 1):
            scrollable_frame.grid_rowconfigure(i, weight=1)

    def show_month_view(self, month):
        self.clear_frame(self.right_frame)

        calendar.setfirstweekday(calendar.MONDAY)  # Set Monday as the first day of the week

        month_label = tk.Label(self.right_frame, text=f"{calendar.month_name[month]} {self.current_year}", font=("Arial", 24))
        month_label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=7, pady=5)

        days = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]
        for col, day in enumerate(days):
            day_label = tk.Label(self.right_frame, text=day, font=("Arial", 14, "bold"), borderwidth=1, relief="solid")
            day_label.grid(row=1, column=col, sticky="nsew")

        month_days = calendar.monthcalendar(self.current_year, month)
        for row, week in enumerate(month_days, start=2):
            for col, day in enumerate(week):
                if day == 0:
                    day_label = tk.Label(self.right_frame, text="", borderwidth=1, relief="solid")
                else:
                    day_label = tk.Label(self.right_frame, text=str(day), borderwidth=1, relief="solid")
                    if self.current_year == self.today.year and month == self.today.month and day == self.today.day:
                        day_label.config(bg="lightblue")
                    day_label.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event, m=month, d=day: self.show_week_view())
                day_label.grid(row=row, column=col, sticky="nsew")

        for i in range(7):
            self.right_frame.grid_columnconfigure(i, weight=1)
        for i in range(len(month_days) + 2):
            self.right_frame.grid_rowconfigure(i, weight=1)

    def clear_frame(self, frame):
        for widget in frame.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()

    def prev_year(self):
        self.current_year -= 1
        self.create_year_view()

    def next_year(self):
        self.current_year += 1
        self.create_year_view()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = CalendarApp(root)
    root.mainloop()


I don't know how to make the grid not shift over. ChatGTP was no use. It just gives me the same solution over and over. Anyone have any thoughts? I tried making the scroll bar function same on the right as the left.
